# Another mysqld server running on port 3306 error

Tags: mysql, installation

I have installed Mysql 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion. For some reason, though, when I try starting the server with the command "mysqld" I get an error in the log file which says:

120328 21:32:40 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use

120328 21:32:40 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

120328 21:32:40 [ERROR] Aborting

If I run "netstat -nat | grep 3306" in my terminal, I get the following:
tcp4       0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN

UPDATE:

So here's the output for that. 
mysqld  24645 sb1752   12u  IPv4 0xffffff8010f6bde0      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)

This is odd though! Because my mysql server is not started.
When I type "mysql" in command line, it says 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I did install other version of mysql and uninstalled earlier today. Any idea what to do here?

Comment: What is the output of `ps -ef " grep mysql`?

Comment: @Tim, How this question became off-topic?

Comment: use `brew services stop mysql` on MacBook Pro then restart mysql either using MAMP pro or `brew services start mysql`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use `netstat -lp | grep 3306` to find out what program is already listening on port 3306 (you should see PID/Program name in last column) and stop that (maybe mysql is already running?).

Alternatively you could start the newly installed server on a different port. (edit `my.cnf` and change the default port there)

Comment: Thanks. How do I stop the other mysql? I thought I only had one. Where would the other one be?

Comment: Try `/etc/init.d/mysqld stop` or use `kill <pid>`

Comment: To get the `<pid>` for the comment above, you can run the command from the answer below. `lsof -i TCP:3306`. Thanks guys

Comment: if the  grep is not recognize then  findstr  can be used

Answer (score 42):

use `lsof -i TCP:3306` to check which program binds port 3306

Comment: this is a nice way as it will also catch any tunnels and whatnot you might have setup. I use scp over tunnels and had bound a tunnel on 3306

Comment: In my case, this answer gave me the way for solving this error. I check a mysqld process is running at that port, and I killed. Then, I could start mysql with restarting mysql server via brew(I guess there was an error on starting mysql server in the two ways: mysql.server and brew services).

Comment: had to add sudo to get it working
sudo lsof -i TCP:3306 then sudo kill [pidid]

Comment: Perfect, ran your command and used answer above to kill the serivce