# How to start mysql in xampp which is showing error?

Tags: php

I have installed xampp in my laptop. But when i am starting mysql, its showing 3306 error port number used by another application. How can I rectify this eroor ?

Comment: It sounds like you have another MYSQL Server instance already installed and running on your Laptop.

Answer (score 2):

you have another program that's using port 3306, so you can change the port of your mysql to like 3307, or close the program that's using that port. 
check this link [mysql port error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918062/another-mysqld-server-running-on-port-3306-error)