# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/`username`.lan.pid)

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I cannot get rid of the error below.

1. Installed homebrew via `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. `brew install mysql`
3. `mysql.server start` gives the error: `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/`username`.lan.pid).`

Some things I have tried:

`ps -ef | grep mysql` outputs:

`501  1196  1172   0  9:08PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mysql`

which I then try to kill with `kill -9 1172`. This just says `Process Complete` but then a new process starts running. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

I have used `sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/` to change ownership and tried running again with no luck.

I have tried running this from the directory `Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨usr⁩ ▸ ⁨local⁩ ▸ ⁨mysql-8.0.14-macos10.14-x86_64` with no luck.

I have tried deleting the error logs and re-running.

I just updated my Mac to Mojave 10.14.3 no luck.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql.

I have tried installing mysql via a download link instead of `brew install`

I tried doing `unset TMPDIR`, `mysql_install_db` but I get the response: `-bash: mysql_install_db: command not found`. I have tried running this from inside the mysql-VERSION folder.

I am not sure what else to try. Help is appreciated.

`.err file`:

```
2019-01-24T19:46:47.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/ryans-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-24T19:46:47.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-24T19:46:47.525951Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 78796
2019-01-24T19:46:47.529750Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-24T19:46:47.535680Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012271] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:46:47.535720Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012278] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:46:47.535747Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2019-01-24T19:46:47.535869Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-01-24T19:46:47.535891Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-24T19:46:47.536598Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-24T19:46:47.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-24T19:47:05.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-24T19:47:05.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-24T19:47:05.861015Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 78949
2019-01-24T19:47:05.864718Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-24T19:47:05.871046Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012271] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:47:05.871084Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012278] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:47:05.871110Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2019-01-24T19:47:05.871264Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-01-24T19:47:05.871290Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-24T19:47:05.871961Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-24T19:47:05.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-24T19:51:27.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-24T19:51:27.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-24T19:51:27.979873Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 81867
2019-01-24T19:51:27.983686Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-24T19:51:27.998082Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012271] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:51:27.998131Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012278] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:51:27.998159Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2019-01-24T19:51:27.998299Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-01-24T19:51:27.998328Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-24T19:51:27.999095Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-24T19:51:28.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-24T19:52:04.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-24T19:52:04.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-24T19:52:04.660514Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 82584
2019-01-24T19:52:04.664208Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-24T19:52:04.670173Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012271] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:52:04.670215Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012278] [InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2019-01-24T19:52:04.670239Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2019-01-24T19:52:04.670387Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-01-24T19:52:04.670416Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-24T19:52:04.671195Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-24T19:52:04.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-24T19:53:38.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-24T19:53:38.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-24T19:53:38.430888Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 82806
2019-01-24T19:53:38.434733Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-24T19:53:38.905784Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000054] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2019-01-24T19:53:38.905899Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010107] [Server] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.
2019-01-24T19:53:38.905985Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010075] [Server] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: be330a06-2011-11e9-8f30-eeb7cad0b310.
2019-01-24T19:53:38.921773Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-24T19:53:38.928389Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-24T19:53:38.928416Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-24T19:53:38.928458Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-24T19:53:40.656950Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-24T19:53:40.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-24T19:59:06.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-24T19:59:06.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-24T19:59:07.597870Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 679
2019-01-24T19:59:07.682119Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-24T19:59:08.398625Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-24T19:59:08.410090Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-24T19:59:08.410134Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-24T19:59:08.410179Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-24T19:59:09.753682Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-24T19:59:09.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-29T03:49:55.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-29T03:49:56.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-29T03:49:56.312175Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 17447
2019-01-29T03:49:56.315809Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-29T03:49:56.760978Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-29T03:49:56.768674Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-29T03:49:56.768706Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-29T03:49:56.768735Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-29T03:49:58.135724Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-29T03:49:58.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-29T04:35:11.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-29T04:35:11.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-29T04:35:11.604233Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 17821
2019-01-29T04:35:11.607955Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-29T04:35:11.904189Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-29T04:35:11.910582Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-29T04:35:11.910605Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-29T04:35:11.910638Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-29T04:35:13.403138Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-29T04:35:13.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-29T04:38:23.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-29T04:38:23.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-29T04:38:23.883516Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 17989
2019-01-29T04:38:23.887192Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2019-01-29T04:38:23.887568Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-29T04:38:23.887755Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-29T04:38:23.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-29T04:39:48.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-29T04:39:48.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-29T04:39:49.266658Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 18103
2019-01-29T04:39:49.270279Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-29T04:39:49.587646Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-29T04:39:49.593469Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-29T04:39:49.593491Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-29T04:39:49.593525Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-29T04:39:50.983373Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-29T04:39:51.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-29T05:04:29.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-29T05:04:29.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-29T05:04:30.224737Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 989
2019-01-29T05:04:30.245235Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-29T05:04:30.797676Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-29T05:04:30.805231Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-29T05:04:30.805265Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-29T05:04:30.805300Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-29T05:04:32.175755Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-29T05:04:32.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
2019-01-29T05:39:19.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.err'.
2019-01-29T05:39:19.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2019-01-29T05:39:19.544597Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.13) starting as process 1882
2019-01-29T05:39:19.551070Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-01-29T05:39:19.984015Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-01-29T05:39:19.991348Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2019-01-29T05:39:19.991394Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-01-29T05:39:19.991430Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-01-29T05:39:21.359167Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.13/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.13)  Homebrew.
2019-01-29T05:39:21.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/-macbook.lan.pid ended
```

Comment: can you show your mysql error logs.

Comment: hmmm i am not actually seeing any error logs anywhere in the mysql folder..

Comment: i am looking in `/usr/local/var/mysql/`username`.lan.pid` and i see a file called `username-macbook.lan.err` but im not sure i can open it. and isnt that `.err` file in the wrong location?

Comment: ok i updated the post with the `.err` file

Answer (score 29):

**Problem:**

I have the same problem also when I installed mysql using homebrew. this case, it come from `/usr/local/var/mysql/` permissions that taken by last mysql version. it's still error even though we use `sudo mysql.server`.

```
$ mysql.server start
```

```sh
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/[username].local.pid).
```

**Solution:**

Here is my solution, I remove `mysql` drictory at `/usr/local/var/mysql/` and start reinstall with homebrew again.  It's work for me what I solved as below:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
```

```
$ brew reinstall mysql
```

**Result:**

```
$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

Comment: I still have the same problem this didn't work.

Comment: This works for me. Do also check the .err file  in `/usr/local/var/mysql/` folder to verify what is the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Sen Sokha's solution which didn't seem to work. Following advice in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file), I cd'd to `/usr/local/var/mysql` & then ran `vim [my-computer's-name].local.err` to read the error logs, which gave me this:  `[ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use.`

I then followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918062/another-mysqld-server-running-on-port-3306-error) and ran `lsof -i TCP:3306` to check what was already running there, then `kill 566` (566 being the PID) to stop it. I ran `mysql.server start` and it worked this time!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, your datadir `/usr/local/var/mysql/` has the wrong permissions.

Homebrew appears to use the [current user of the brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb#L156)  and is this user that should own the datadir and all contents underneath.

mysql_install_db was removed in MySQL-8.0.

Comment: Hi @danblack  does the `sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/` not set permissions of mysql? I think I have tried this

Comment: I saw. No, not `mysql`, the user you are logged into as when you did the `brew install`

Comment: so i should uninstall mysql and then reinstall with maybe `sudo`?

Answer (score -1):

If using an Apple Silicon processor, run the following to remove the mysql directory

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/
```

Then restart mysql

```
brew services restart mysql
```